# TortoiseSvn how see logs for unversion folders and files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This is the situation:

- I have a folder x, subversion with log for every revision[ ex:rev 1 -> log 1, rev2 -> log2 ]
- I unversioned and add to ignore list the folder x. And commit to svn
- After commit i try to revert to folder but my tortoise svn not responsing and crushed.
- I added the folder x to svn and commited with revision 100 -> log 100

Now i can't see old revision or old log[ log1, log2, etc].
I try to update to revision[ rev1 in this case] but same probleme the log not see.

Do you have some trick or advice  to see the old logs for unversioned folder x ??

I use the last version TortoiseSVN 1.9.5

Answer (score 0):

If you solely use TortoiseSVN's interface, open [Revision Log dialog](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html) for parent directory and look for the commit that removed the folder that you are looking for. Right-click the folder in the list of changed paths and select Show Log command.

Note that the correct way to re-add the folder that you added to ignores and unversion is to [undo the commit with deletion](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html#tsvn-howto-rollback-log). Or run `svn copy` command as suggested in [Resurrecting deleted items](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html).